# creating 2d array from 1d arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

if i have several arrays of the same datatype, what is the best way to copy them all into a 2d array. for example

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int array2[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

int array2d[][];
//pseudo code array2d = array1 + array2
```

so that

```
array2d[0][0]; //=1 (first member of array1)
array2d[1][0]; //=9 (first member of array2)
```

considering an array is just a pointer to the first element, i thought I could do this, but it creates a compiler error.

```
array2d[0][0] = array1;
array2d[1][0] = array2;
```

I'm guessing I can't copy using references because an array needs its entries in contiguous memory? is there a memset like funciton I can use?

Comment: "considering an array is just a pointer to the first element"... nah, nah, nah, an array is not a pointer to the first element, which explains why it does not work (further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible. You need to copy element by element from one array to another.

Also you can mimic 2d array with array of pointers to arrays of ints.

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int array2[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

int *array2d[2]; 

array2d[0] = array1;
array2d[1] = array2;
```

or this

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int array2[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

int *array2d[] = {array1, array2}; 

cout << "[0][0]=" << array2d[0][0] << endl;
cout << "[1][0]=" << array2d[1][0] << endl;
```

**OR REVERSE**

If your goal is to present 2d array to some API, then you should refactor your side. For example, you can mimic your 1d arrays with pointers:

```
// an ampty array
int array2d[2][10];

// pointers to parts
int *array1 = array2d[0];
int *array2 = array2d[1];

int n;

// fill "arrays"
for(int i=0, n=1; i<10; ++i, ++n) {
    array1[i] = n;
}
for(int i=0, n=9; i<10; ++i, --n) {
    array2[i] = n;
}

// now you are ready
cout << "[0][0]=" << array2d[0][0] << endl;
cout << "[1][0]=" << array2d[1][0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an actual 2D array (contiguous in memory), you'll have to copy the elements. However, you could emulate it with an array of 2 pointers:

```
int *array2d[2];
array2d[0] = array1;
array2d[1] = array2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an actual 2D array, but you could make `array2d` an array of pointers to the 1d arrays:

```
int* array2d[2];

array2d[0] = array1;
array2d[1] = array2;
```

Otherwise you'll have to copy the elements over manually.

Comment: thats how i would normally do it but its to send to an api function expecting an array like '**datatype'

Comment: does the API expect `**datatype` or `datatype[][]`? You should probably read the question linked in the comments, there is a lot of good information there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that you can do. If you know that your data is going to be constant within each array, you can `#define` it, and then use it in your 1D and 2D arrays. Alternatively, you can memcpy the elements from the 1D array to the 2D array. The second point is illustrated here:

```
#define ARRAY_1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
#define ARRAY_2 {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }

int array_1[] = ARRAY_1;
int array_2[] = ARRAY_2;

int two_dim_array[][] = {
    ARRAY_1,
    ARRAY_2,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Define and assign**:

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int array2[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

int *array2d[2];
array2d[0] = array1;
array2d[1] = array2;
```

**Test**:

```
printf("%d\t",array2d[0][0]);
printf("%d\t",array2d[0][9]);
printf("%d\t",array2d[1][5]);
```

it gives `1 10  4`